# Changing of Listview Button State when pressed for position

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I have a Listview, in which every row has play button. If i clicked on First Play Button it changes to pause but if i pressed second row play button,then first will remain in pause state but i want that if any of button is pressed then the previous button back to its play state and the clicked one changes to pause.
Code is below.

```
public class RingsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Ringsinfo> data;
private SqlLiteDbHelper db;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
int pause_button_position = -1;

public RingsAdapter(Context mContext) {
    data = new ArrayList<Ringsinfo>();
    context = mContext;
    initDatabase(context);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}

private void initDatabase(Context c) {
    db = new SqlLiteDbHelper(c);
    try {
        db.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
        db.openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void AddAll(ArrayList<Ringsinfo> listperson) {
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(listperson);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return (Ringsinfo) this.data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long) position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HolderView mHolderView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        mHolderView = new HolderView();
        convertView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.row_ringtone_list, parent, false);
        mHolderView.btnPlay = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        mHolderView.btnSetting = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSetting);
        mHolderView.tvRingName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRingName);
        convertView.setTag(mHolderView);
    } else {
        mHolderView = (HolderView) convertView.getTag();
    }
    mHolderView.tvRingName.setText(((Ringsinfo) this.data.get(position)).name);
    mHolderView.btnSetting.setOnClickListener(new RingDetails(position));
    mHolderView.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new playRingtone(position));

    if (position != pause_button_position)
        mHolderView.btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.play);

    return convertView;
}

class RingDetails implements View.OnClickListener {
    final int val$position;

    RingDetails(int i) {
        this.val$position = i;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RingDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("calls", ((Ringsinfo) data.get(this.val$position)).content);
        intent.putExtra("heading", ((Ringsinfo) data.get(this.val$position)).name);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

class playRingtone implements View.OnClickListener {
    int val$position;

    playRingtone(int i) {
        val$position = i;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.play);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pause);
            pause_button_position = val$position;
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, new Builder().scheme("android.resource").authority(context.getPackageName()).appendPath(String.valueOf(context.getResources().getIdentifier(((Ringsinfo) data.get(val$position)).content + BuildConfig.FLAVOR, "raw", context.getPackageName()))).build());
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

private class HolderView {
    private Button btnPlay, btnSetting;
    private TextView tvRingName;
}

public void Stop() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `else` condition in your Adapter where you change your background for `ImageView`

```
if (position != pause_button_position)
        mHolderView.btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.play);
else
        mHolderView.btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.pause);
```

Also, It would be good if you manage one Boolean list in `Adapter` to manager your play pause button. 
Like your `Boolean` list is same size of your `ArrayList`. once user click on 1st play button then you need to set true at 1st position of Boolean List and rest of are false. Same way if user click on 2nd play button then set true at 2nd position of your `Boolean` List and keep rest of false and notify your `Adapter`. 
and your play pause button background is now based on Boolean List.

Comment: Above code, doesn't effect on my code, still the problem is same.